test in jmeter doesn't stop
I ran a test in jmeter for authorization and further verification for 2500 usersenter image description here
after successfully passing the test, I see that time is ticking, the test doesn't stop
POST auth] (https://i.sstatic.net/eAdtEMnv.png)
log of jmeter
enter image description here
the test runs until I stop it through the terminal, what's the problem?
I don’t understand what’s wrong, for 10 users everything is fine, but when I want to select 2500 users the test goes on without stopping

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Don't run test in GUI mode, it's for test development and/or debugging. When it comes to test execution you should run your test in command-line non-GUI mode

Disable or remove all Listeners, especially View Results Tree, it doesn't add any value but consumes a lot of resources

It might be the case the system under test is overloaded and cannot respond to requests. By default JMeter will wait for the response forever so it might be a good idea to set reasonable response timeouts. The setting lives under "Advanded" tab of the HTTP Request sampler. If you have more than one HTTP Request sampler you can set timeouts in one place using HTTP Request Defaults



